# How I use the head command for the files in current directory and subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If I use `head *.txt | less`, it will display the head of all files with *.txt in the current directory? What if I wish to display the head of all files with .txt residing in current directory and subdirectories.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You could use find:

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec head {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell supports it (zsh does, not sure about the rest), you can use `**` syntax:

```
head **/*.txt
```

Comment: This is also supported in Bash 4 with `shopt -s globstar` or with `ksh` with `set -o globstar`.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing; here's what worked for me (I output the response to the file headtest.txt). Note that this will move through the current directory and the subdirectories.

```
find . -type f -exec head '{}' \; >> headtest.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use -

```
find -name '*.txt' | xargs head
```

Please note that -name need not work in all environments
In that case, you can use

```
find . | grep ".txt" | xargs head
```

Comment: I've never heard of `-name` not working, but it's not uncommon for `find` to complain about missing arguments using your second form (at least in old versions).